# Select alternating groups of 4

Tags: css, css-selectors

Not even sure this can be done. Haven't seen any such examples yet.

I want 4 rows matched then 4 rows not matched, etc.

```
      match: 1,2,3,4, 9,10,11,12, 17, etc.
don't match: 5,6,7,8, 13,14,15,16 etc.
```

It's a 24hr timetable in 15 minute increments. This way, each hour will be highlighted.

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm? Is this in the context of a database (i.e. SQL query)? Or what..?

Comment: Terribly sorry. As mentioned in the title, this is a CSS selector.

So I'm looking for an algorithm like li:nth-child(4n+1) or somesuch. The trick is what CSS selector algorithms are limited to.

Comment: It occurs to me that my table has a fixed number of rows. That means, worst possible case, I can always make all 12 selectors manually.

Answer (score 5):

Oh I see now. It's pretty straightforward now that I've been playing with offset selectors.

:nth-child(8n+1) will match every 8th row starting at the first.
Then I can just add more selectors with other offsets: (8n+2), (8n+3), (8n+4)

So:

```
li{
    background-color: white;
}
li:nth-child(8n+1),
li:nth-child(8n+2),
li:nth-child(8n+3),
li:nth-child(8n+4){
    background-color: #EEE;
}
```

Now I get 4 rows of grey, followed by 4 rows of white, exactly what I want.

Comment: You're right, it is straightforward. I've been beating myself up trying to come up with an answer for you and had been overthinking it. Nicely done.